# Как изменить цвет текста в IDLE python shell?

Tags: python, python-3.x, idle

Подскажите как изменить цвет текста в python shell встроенными методами потому, что при использовании этого кода:
`print("\x1b[7;30;41m" + "\nSomething" + "\x1b[0m")` выдаётся не то что нужно:

```
[7;30;41mSomething[0m
```

Я знаю, что есть библиотеки(termcolor,clint...), но мне интересно как это сделать без них.

Использую python 3.6

Comment: В какой консоли запускаете-то?

Comment: Использую python 3.6

Comment: Это понятно, а консоль-то какая?

Comment: IDLE. Вы это имеете ввиду?

Comment: IDLE вроде бы не поддерживает ANSI, в ней этот код и не должен работать. См. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42472958/how-do-i-print-colored-text-in-idles-terminal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[IDLE не поддерживает ни `\b` ни `\r`](https://bugs.python.org/issue23220) ни [управляющие символы ANSI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_ANSI).

Чтобы вывести цветной текст, можно использовать средства, специфичные для IDLE. К примеру, используя [`idlecolors` модуль](https://github.com/lawsie/idlecolors):

[image: screenshot idle colored text]